# Extract columns from row values in Python

Tags: pandas, pivot

I am using this dataframe:

```
dfPredET.head(5)

id  Class
1   Class_2
2   Class_1
3   Class_6
4   Class_2
5   Class_1
```

and I would like to transforms it indicating if one instance belongs to a class (1) or not (0):

```
id  Class_1 Class_2 Class_3 Class_4 Class_5 Class_6 Class_7 Class_8 Class_9
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
4   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Can I do that using `pivot()` function? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas.get_dummies):

```
In [7]:

pd.get_dummies(df)
Out[7]:
   id  Class_Class_1  Class_Class_2  Class_Class_6
0   1              0              1              0
1   2              1              0              0
2   3              0              0              1
3   4              0              1              0
4   5              1              0              0
```